# Send a Json array POST request with android using volley

Tags: android, arrays, json, android-volley

i am developing application in which i send data to server using volley now i want to send data to server in json array but not know how to send in array??

```
    Map<String, String> postParam = new HashMap<String, String>();

    postParam.put("Token", "U2FsdGVkX13CFEM=");
    postParam.put("AppDB", "day");
    postParam.put("ContentTypeName", "Users");



    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            AppConfig.URL_REGISTER_WITHOUT_IMG, new JSONObject(postParam),
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                    //     msgResponse.setText(response.toString());
                    //  hideProgressDialog();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            // hideProgressDialog();
        }
    }) {

        /**
         * Passing some request headers
         * */
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
            headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
            return headers;
        }
    };

    jsonObjReq.setTag(TAG);
    // Adding request to request queue
    Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(jsonObjReq);

}
```

now i want to send data in array expected json 
{
    "AppDb":"day",
    "ContentTypeName":"Users",
    "Token":"U2FsdGVkX13CFEM=",
    "FilterData":[
        {"FilterName":"EmailId","FilterValue":" Pass the user enter email here to check"}    ]

}

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
JSONArray jsonArray=new JSONArray();
JSONObject jsonObj=new JSONObject();
try {
    jsonObj.put("filterName","EmailId");
    jsonObj.put("FilterValue",// user email);
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
jsonArray.put(jsonObj);
```

Add it to your params like this:

```
postParam.put("FilterData",jsonArray);
```

Comment: thanks for quick response @Prashanth Verma one more when i send in postParam.put("FilterData",jsonArray); JsonArray give error showing is it convert into string?

Comment: Oh..because you are using Map<String, String> thats why. Just try converting into string

Comment: postParam.put("FilterData", String.valueOf(jsonArray)); @ Prashanth Verma
my debugger not enter into volley reponse and not in error respone why?

Comment: Try this: postParam.put("FilterData", jsonArray.toString());

Answer (score 0):

Following three steps should make it work for old Volley libraries lacking this suport.

1. Prepare payload and post:

   JSONArray payloadItems = new JSONArray();

   JSONObject payloadItem1=new JSONObject();
    //set properties on item1
    payloadItem1.put('prop1',"val11");

   payloadItems.put(payloadItem1);

   JSONObject payloadItem2=new JSONObject();
    //set properties on item1
    payloadItem2.put('prop1',"val12");

   payloadItems.put(payloadItem1);

   JsonArrayRequest request;

   request = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.POST,url,payloadItems, new Response.Listener() {
       @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
       @Override
       public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
           //your logic to handle response
       }
   }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
       @Override
       public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
           //your logic to handle error
       }
   }) {

   ```
   public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
       Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
       /* This is very important to pass along */
       params.put("Content-Type","application/json");
       //other headers if any
       return params;
   }

    };
   ```
2. [If Needed] Add this constructor in Class- JsonArrayRequest in Volley package if not already there

   ```
     public JsonArrayRequest(int method, String url, JSONArray jsonArray, Listener<JSONArray> listener, ErrorListener errorListener) {
       super(method, url, (jsonArray == null) ? null : jsonArray.toString(),
               listener, errorListener);
   ```

   }
3. [If Needed] Override this method if not yet implemented to support JSONArray response from server.

   ```
    @Override
    protected Response<JSONArray> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
        String responseString;
        JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
        if (response != null) {

            try {
                responseString = new String(response.data, HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(responseString);
                (array).put(obj);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
            }
        }
        //return array;
        return Response.success(array, 
        HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
    }
   ```