# PUT Request for Json with Json array inside

Tags: android, json, retrofit2, android-volley, put

I'm trying to update a PUT request which has a JSONArray inside it and I'm constantly getting a 500 error response. Here how the api structure is:

```
{
    "imei": 514515854152463,
    "franquia": "SAO",
    "sistema": "PEGASUS",
    "lista": 2055313,
    "entregas":[
        {
            "codHawb": "02305767706",
            "dataHoraBaixa": "2020-12-03T15:26:22",
            "foraAlvo": 1000,
             "latitude": 44.4545,
            "longitude": 45.545,
            "nivelBateria": 98,
            "tipoBaixa": "ENTREGA"
        }
    ]
}
```

I've tried the api in Postman to see if its working and it is. But when I'm trying it in the program using Volley I'm getting that error. I've tried volley and here is the code:

```
 private void PutJsonRequest() {
        try {
            Map<String, String> postParam = new HashMap<String, String>();
            postParam.put("imei", "514515854152463");
            postParam.put("franquia", preferences.getFranchise());
            postParam.put("sistema", preferences.getSystem());
            postParam.put("lista", preferences.getListID());
            postParam.put("dataHoraBaixa", "2020-12-03T15:26:22");
            postParam.put("foraAlvo", "100");
            postParam.put("latitude", "45.545");
            postParam.put("longitude", " 45.554");
            postParam.put("nivelBateria", "98");
            postParam.put("tipoBaixa", "ENTREGA");
            JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.PUT, ApiUtils.GET_LIST + preferences.getListID(), new JSONObject(postParam), new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "PUTonResponse: " + response);

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "PUTonResponseError: " + error);

                }
            }) {
                @Override
                public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                    HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    String auth1 = "Basic "
                            + Base64.encodeToString((preferences.getUserName() + ":" + preferences.getPass()).getBytes(),
                            Base64.NO_WRAP);
                    params.put("Authorization", auth1);
                    params.put("x-ver", "3.0");
                    params.put("x-ras", "rick");
                    params.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
                    return params;
                }

                @Override
                public String getBodyContentType() {
                    return "application/json";
                }
            };
            queue.add(request);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

[Here is the result in postman:1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4BExc.png)

[Here is the result in postman:2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eObaK.png)

The problem is there is an array in the api, I've tried the above in the way if there are only JSON object but it is not working, please help me know if anything can be updated or done in different way for sending arrays either in volley or retrofit. Thanks.

//Edit:

I tried sending the params in another way and this was also giving the same 500 error:

```
 JSONArray jsonArray=new JSONArray();
        JSONObject jsonObj=new JSONObject();

        try {

            jsonObj.put("codHawb", "02305767706");
            jsonObj.put("dataHoraBaixa", "2020-12-03T15:26:22");
            jsonObj.put("foraAlvo", "100");
            jsonObj.put("latitude", "-46.86617505263801");
            jsonObj.put("longitude", " -23.214458905023452");
            jsonObj.put("nivelBateria", "98");
            jsonObj.put("tipoBaixa", "ENTREGA");
            jsonArray.put(jsonObj);

            Map<String, String> postParam = new HashMap<String, String>();
            postParam.put("imei", "514515854152463");
            postParam.put("franquia", preferences.getFranchise());
            postParam.put("sistema", preferences.getSystem());
            postParam.put("lista", preferences.getListID());
            postParam.put("entregas",jsonArray.toString());
```

Comment: follow this your sending wrong parms to server  
https://stackoverflow.com/a/52131551/4142961

Comment: @IrfanUllah Thanks for the reply, in that answer I see how to send the array but I need to send JsonObject and the array. In the api, I need to send the im, franquia... and the array list  below, I tried it and still getting the 500 error.

Comment: I've updated the question on how I tried, please check @IrfanUllah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out, sending the PUT request in the form of api. FYI: If you have multiple json objects inside the array, just use a for loop, here is the working answer:

```
 private void PutJsonRequest() {
        JSONArray jsonArray=new JSONArray();
        JSONObject jsonObj=new JSONObject();
        JSONObject jsonObj1=new JSONObject();
        try {

            jsonObj.put("codHawb", "02305767706");
            jsonObj.put("dataHoraBaixa", "2020-12-03T15:26:22");
            jsonObj.put("foraAlvo", "100");
            jsonObj.put("latitude", "45.222");
            jsonObj.put("longitude", " 23.23452");
            jsonObj.put("nivelBateria", "98");
            jsonObj.put("tipoBaixa", "ENTREGA");
            jsonArray.put(jsonObj);

            jsonObj1.put("imei", preferences.getIMEI());
            jsonObj1.put("franquia", preferences.getFranchise());
            jsonObj1.put("sistema", preferences.getSystem());
            jsonObj1.put("lista", preferences.getListID());
            jsonObj1.put("entregas", jsonArray);

            Log.e(TAG, "PutJsonRequest: "+jsonObj1 );

            JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.PUT, ApiUtils.GET_LIST + preferences.getListID(),jsonObj1, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "PUTonResponse: " + response);

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "PUTonResponseError: " + error);

                }
            }) {
                @Override
                public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                    HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    String auth1 = "Basic "
                            + Base64.encodeToString((preferences.getUserName() + ":" + preferences.getPaso()).getBytes(),
                            Base64.NO_WRAP);
                    params.put("Authorization", auth1);
                    params.put("x-versao-rt", "3.8.10");
                    params.put("x-rastreador", "ricardo");
//                    params.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
                    params.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
                    return params;
                }

                @Override
                public String getBodyContentType() {
                    return "application/json; charset=utf-8";
                }
            };
            request.setTag(TAG);
            queue.add(request);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment if anyone has a doubt.